# Can a system of 10 planets be stable if star is not on the main sequence?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, science-in-society, stars, astrophysics

My star is 2.17 Solar masses. For narrative purposes, I decided this so it will collapse in the theoretical Quark star. Could such a big star that isn't on the main sequence (Because it is class A, not class B) be stable and able to sustain 10 planets, some of which sustain life? Or would the UV output be too high for atmospheric retention due to habitability distance?

Comment: What is atmospheric retention of U light???

Comment: Uv light output by the Sun, Atmospheric retention of planets. It is said that atmospheres evaporate with the hot temperatures and a lot of UV light the sun gives

Comment: Why would it not be on the main sequence? Spectralclass A and B are on the main sequence. As long it isn't a B or O star planets are plausabile, since those two spectral classes evaporate their protoplanetary discs before planet formation can happen. 10 planets are fine if they are spaced out properly or better yet in resonances. UV will be hard on life and it may never leave the few habitable worlds oceans.

Comment: Hi, @SPYRX, welcome to Worldbuilding! Can you please clarify your question (and title)? I see 3 questions here - "Would this system be gravitationally stable?", "Would planets of A-type star be able to support life?" and "Would A-star planetary system survive its star collapse (potentially through a supernova explosion)?"

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, The principal question is Would planets of A-type star be able to support advanced life (like a civilizations of type II)?

Comment: 2.17 solar masses is fairly small; you'd need a star of 8 solar masses - minimum - to undergo a supernova that could form your quark star.

Comment: So I don't know if the mass you have is right, and I don't know if the spectrum is right. From the sounds of it the main way that you would get a quark star is to have a very big start go through a supernova, form a neutron star of just the right size, which would turn into a quark star. A few of those phases aren't going to be good for life, or planets. But I did find one source that said that a quark star could have been created in the early cosmic phase separations following the Big Bang, meaning that it would have been able to get an accretion disk and form planets directly.